# как спарсить картинку с сайта? на python django

Tags: python, django

```
<div class="book_cover">
      <img src="https://s9.knigavuhe.org/2/covers/40032/1-2@2x.jpg?1" alt="Должник">
    </div>
```

Comment: s9, s10, s12 все эти ссылки уникальные

Comment: ну как, возьми ссылку внутри src и сохрани ее

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим такую ситуацию:
У нас есть файл index.html, в котором есть заветная картинка.
В таком случае можно попробовать вот так

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

with open('index.html', 'r') as f:
    src = f.read()
soup = BS(src, 'lxml')
img = soup.find('img')
img_content = requests.get(img['src']).content

with open('img.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(img_content)
```